# JTS server unable to fetch root service document for other CLM Apps

Tags: ibm-jazz

I am staging our CLM test environment with Prod data with version V6.0.3 and iFix011a .If I access the below uls, I see server rename is completed for all the apps ccm,qm,rm, rs and dcc

https:///app_name/rootservices

https:///app_name/appServerRenameStatus

But server rename status is not updated in JTS UI. As per jts.log JTS is unable to fetch root services document dor all apps and returs HHT code 500. Below is the excerpt of the error.

2018-06-05 16:50:07,135 [                     Thread-64]  INFO ping.internal.ServerRenameOverallStatusRestService  - Server rename details:Unable to contact https:///dcc/rootservices : org.apache.http.HttpException: While fetching the root services document from "https:///dcc/rootservices" a "500" HTTP status code was received
        at com.ibm.team.jfs.app.discovery.utils.RootServicesUtil.parseResponse(RootServicesUtil.java:834)
        at com.ibm.team.jfs.app.discovery.utils.RootServicesUtil.fetchRootServices(RootServicesUtil.java:785)
        at com.ibm.team.jfs.app.discovery.utils.RootServicesUtil.access$0(RootServicesUtil.java:747)
        at com.ibm.team.jfs.app.discovery.utils.RootServicesUtil$CachedResourceManager.run(RootServicesUtil.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

2018-06-05 16:50:07,147 [                     Thread-64]  INFO ping.internal.ServerRenameOverallStatusRestService  - Server rename details:Unable to contact https:///rs/rootservices : org.apache.http.HttpException: While fetching the root services document from "https:///rs/rootservices" a "500" HTTP status code was received
        at com.ibm.team.jfs.app.discovery.utils.RootServicesUtil.parseResponse(RootServicesUtil.java:834)
        at com.ibm.team.jfs.app.discovery.utils.RootServicesUtil.fetchRootServices(RootServicesUtil.java:785)
        at com.ibm.team.jfs.app.discovery.utils.RootServicesUtil.access$0(RootServicesUtil.java:747)
        at com.ibm.team.jfs.app.discovery.utils.RootServicesUtil$CachedResourceManager.run(RootServicesUtil.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

2018-06-05 16:50:07,147 [                     Thread-64]  INFO ping.internal.ServerRenameOverallStatusRestService  - Server rename details:
The following server rename status was received from the application:
        Application Name: /ccm
        Percent Complete: 0
        State: COMPLETED
        Result: ERROR
        Result Message: CRJAZ2373E The server could not retrieve the server rename status for application "/ccm". Please consult the log files for more details
2018-06-05 16:50:07,148 [                     Thread-64]  INFO ping.internal.ServerRenameOverallStatusRestService  - Server rename details:
The following server rename status was received from the application:
        Application Name: /qm
        Percent Complete: 0
        State: COMPLETED
        Result: ERROR

Any idea why JTS is unable to fetch the root services for other apps?

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue while we were doing server rename.

1. the first time we completed the steps with one final error at the end.
2. the second time when we tried to redo the serverRenameStatus was showing the same error as the one that you mentioned.

Solution: place the mappingEvent file in /conf/jts and redo the serverRenameStatus and it will work like a charm.

mappingEvent file disappears from jts once the serverRenameStatus is completed.